# Installing nexmo-php SMS API without using Composer

Tags: php, vonage

I need to send SMS via API and I am having problems installing [NEXMO](https://www.nexmo.com).

There are only instructions on how to install via Composer, which I am not familiar with and seems complex. The site support is terrible.

Any idea on how to install [nexmo libraries](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-php) onto my provider's server?

Comment: Download composer And run a single command Is complex? Just give it a go...

Comment: Composer was successfully installed but now I type on the terminal "require nexmo/client" and nothing happens. "sh: require: command not found"

Comment: It's `composer require nexmo/client`

Comment: @barmar. It says: "sh: composer: command not found"

Comment: you may need to type the full path to the `composer` script if you didn't install it in one of the standard bin directories.

Comment: How can I run composer from the Server?

Comment: Depending how you installed it, you may be able to do `composer require nexmo/client` - or you may need to run `php composer.phar require nexmo/client` if you downloaded a phar file

Answer (score 1):

Composer is the industry standard for all libraries and is our recommended route for installation - it would be tricky and time-consuming to bring in all the dependencies and get them to autoload correctly when doing this manually. However there is no requirement to use the PHP library, you may find it simpler to make HTTP calls from PHP using either curl (if it is installed), or streams (always available, less friendly for beginners). You can find the API reference here https://developer.nexmo.com/api/sms

You mention that "the site support is terrible", could you say a bit more about what you found disappointing? We're always looking for ways to improve our documentation so it would be good to hear what didn't work well for you here, even if it feels a bit negative.

Comment: The support team continuously replies with links to documentation pages but never addresses the specific question. I gave up

Comment: I'm sorry that you felt that our documentation wasn't useful. It does refer to Composer for installation of the (entirely optional) PHP library, you won't find many PHP libraries that don't install this way I'm afraid. Please do go ahead and try calling the API directly though if you don't want dependencies in your code, the libraries are meant to make things easier but they are not required. If you know how to call an API, then you can call Nexmo's API however you wish.

Comment: Ok will try. Thank you